# Complex border line Design

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive-design, border, screen

I want to create a dynamic grid view like this image.

[image]

But I am facing a problem with this type of line border. Is there any way to initialize Container border start and end position ? Otherwise what is the best way to build this UI?

Comment: while this is just 6 items, you can design N items.  More about [Border](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border-class.html#painting.Border.2)

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Did you notice that, border is not completely end?

Comment: I am talking about border line

Comment: You can also use row and column to create the UI. It would be nice if you include your best effort?

Answer (score 0):

I done with `Wrap()` widget. here is my dummy List [], and here is my code

```
 final List<String> items = [
      'Item 1',
      'Item 2',
      'Item 3',
      'Item 4',
      'Item 5'
    ];



Wrap(
  runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
  spacing: 0,
  runSpacing: 0,
  children: items.map((item) {
    final index = items.indexOf(item);
    final isOdd = index.isOdd;
    final isEven = index.isEven;
    final isLastItem = index == items.length - 1;

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: (Get.width - 112.w) / 2,
          height: (Get.width - 144.w) / 2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.w),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              left: isOdd ? BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
              right: isEven ? BorderSide(width: isLastItem ? 1.0 : 0.5, color: borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text("$item, ")),
        ),
        if (!isLastItem)
          SizedBox(
            width: (Get.width - 112.w) / 2,
            child: Divider(
              endIndent: 16.w,
              indent: 16.w,
              height: 32.h,
              thickness: 1.0,
              color: borderColor,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```